# How to change the property of object using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid. Under 'options.models' I have 3 list of which one is datetime. I want to access that property and perform some parsing on date. Since I am new to coding I don't have any idea on that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        angular.forEach(options.models, function(value) {
            //****???****//
        })
        return options;
    }
 }
```

Comment: please post `options.models` array

Comment: Array[3]
0:Object
Batch_No:"B3"
Exp_Dt:Sun Feb 26 2017 16:44:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Id:0
Mfg_Dt:Sun Feb 26 2017 16:44:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Product_Name:"P3"
Product_Type:"T3"
Strip_No:5
Strip_Unit:6
Total:0
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lets assume you want to change 'Exp_Dt" then try this

```
angular.forEach($scope.arr, function(value) {
    value.Exp_Dt = new Date(); // assign whatever date 
})
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.arr = [{
 Exp_Dt: "Sun Feb 26 2017 16: 44: 31 GMT + 0530(India Standard Time)",
 Id: 0,
 Mfg_Dt: "Sun Feb 26 2017 16: 44: 31 GMT + 0530(India Standard Time)",
 Product_Name: "P3",
 Product_Type: "T3",
 Strip_No: 5,
 Strip_Unit: 6,
 Total: 0
}];

 angular.forEach($scope.arr, function(value) {
           value.Exp_Dt = new Date(); // assign whatever date 
        })
    console.log($scope.arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So now my code looks like this. Thanks @Sachila that worked for me.

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        angular.forEach(options.models, function (value) {
                            value.Mfg_Dt = kendo.toString(value.Mfg_Dt, "s");
                        })
                        return options;
                    }
                }
```